# Can you do a group by with find_each in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to write a function that groups by some columns in a very large table (millions of rows).  Is there any way to get `find_each` to work with this, or is it impossible given that I do not want to order by the id column?

The SQL of my query is:
`SELECT derivable_type, derivable_id FROM "mytable" GROUP BY derivable_type, derivable_id ORDER BY "mytable"."id" ASC;`

The rails `find_each` automatically adds the ORDER BY clause using a `reorder` statement.  I have tried changing the SQL to:

`SELECT MAX(id) AS "mytable"."id", derivable_type, derivable_id FROM "mytable" GROUP BY derivable_type, derivable_id ORDER BY "mytable"."id" ASC;`

but that doesn't work either.  Any ideas other than writing my own find_each function or overriding the private `batch_order` function in batches.rb?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two approaches to solve this problem:

**I. Use subquery:**

```
# query the table and select id, derivable_type and derivable_id
my_table_ids = MyTable
  .group("derivable_type, derivable_id")
  .select("MAX(id) AS my_table_id, derivable_type, derivable_id")

# use subquery to allow rails to use ORDER BY in find_each 
MyTable
  .where(id: my_table_ids.select('my_table_id'))
  .find_each { |row| do_something(row) }
```

**II. Write custom find_each function**

```
rows = MyTable
  .group("derivable_type, derivable_id")
  .select("derivable_type, derivable_id")

find_each_grouped(rows, ['derivable_type', 'derivable_id']) do |row| 
  do_something(row)
end

def find_each_grouped(rows, columns, &block)
  offset = 0
  batch_size = 1_000
  loop do
    batch = rows
      .order(columns)
      .offset(offset)
      .limit(limit)

    batch.each(&block)

    break if batch.size < limit
    offset += limit
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but your query looks the same as doing an aggregate distinct()

```
SELECT derivable_type, derivable_id FROM "mytable" GROUP BY derivable_type, derivable_id ORDER BY "mytable"."id" ASC;
---- vv
SELECT DISTINCT(derivable_type, derivable_id) FROM "mytable" ORDER BY "mytable"."id" ASC;
```

You should be able to use Active Record to accomplish this, combined with find_each (if `Mytable` is your model):

```
Mytable.all.group(:derivable_type, :derivable_id).distinct.find_each
# gives => #<Enumerator: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [...]>:find_each({:start=>nil, :finish=>nil, :batch_size=>1000, :error_on_ignore=>nil})>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the thought.  I tried out the SQL you suggested (and Active Record code as well), but I still get the same type of error as in my original post.  This error is: `ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

Comment: Hrmm.. can you provide your table schema? I'd like to try and replicate it locally.